# How to cancel a playing sound started with AudioServicesPlaySystemSound?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-audio, audiotoolbox

Is there a way to cancel, pause or stop a sound that started playing through a call to AudioServicesPlaySystemSound()?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't - like the name suggests, it's designed for playing sounds to be used for system alerts, where you don't need to have control over them. You can *stop* a sound played through `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound()` by calling `AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID()`, but this is a hacky and best avoided.

The best option for straightforward, simple control of audio playback is to use `AVPlayer`, part of `AVFoundation` - documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: `AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID()` cancels nice nice, tested for `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound().`